# What is simplest way to decode and display RTP(MPEG4 TS)

Tags: video

I am working on a small video chat software on windows which use RTP containning MPEG4 TS that I need to decode and display.

I don't need some senior control of the video quality,  and I don't want to write a jitter-buffer.

So which library should I use?  What is simplest way to decode and display RTP(MPEG4 TS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very good library in C is of course [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/). It is a bit hard to use as it is low-level. You can use an interesting C++ wrapper : [FOBS](http://fobs.sourceforge.net/) which has JMF bindings too. If it is not enough, a great C++ library for managing the RTP part is [Live555](http://www.live555.com/).

You can also try to use [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu) or [vlc](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) library part, but it is not easy to integrate as is.